# Is this Nick guy's phrases common(real)?

Tags: american-english, slang

[**This video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oy75vjYOdbY) features an American (speaking Japanese well) called Nick is showing us what kind of slang is used in the U.S. **But he said the U.S is so large that it depends on where you come from**, (Nick is from California) so I would like to confirm with you if the below phrase is used in reality where you come from.

What interested me are,

## 1 Break a leg

Meaning wish something good happen.

## 2 Knock on wood

Meaning the same above

## 3 Crash

So drunk or tired etc that someone is going to borrow another's bed to sleep.

## 4 Jack someone

Meaning, steal something from someone.

Are the above 3 used everywhere in the U.S?

Thank you.

Comment: 1 to 3 are so common we use them in the UK too, although for 2 we say 'touch wood'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks! Looks like The U.K and the U.S is so common in terms of phrasing..

Comment: We use 'touch wood' not so much for good luck, more to prevent a specific kind of bad luck that has just been mentioned, e.g. I will go on vacation next week if I don't get sick - touch wood! At this point the speaker looks around for something made of wood and touches it (does need to knock) and if nothing of wood is found, can touch their own head.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey huh. It looks like it is an old folk tale.

Answer (score 2):

"Break a leg" is limited to the theatre (there is a superstition that you should never wish an actor "good luck" because that will be bad luck! So you wish that they "break a leg")

> Ok, you're on in 5 minutes.  Check your make up and, break a leg!

"knock on wood" is common enough, but also "touch wood". Usually people try to actually touch something wooden when they say this. But some people touch their head. There is an [example of this in the film "Casablanca"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_f8snT93Bc).  You particularly say it when  you predict something about the future

> I'm going to start university this autumn, touch wood, so I'm setting up a bank account.

"Crash" is common slang.

> If you're tried you can crash at my place. It's just round the corner.

"Jack" in this sense is AmE only. Most Americans would know it.

> Someone jacked my seat!

The problem with slang is that it changes so fast that by the time it is documented and described, it is out of date.